# Fourier transform of a pyramid

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Has anyone calculated the Fourier coefficients for a pyramid function?
Let us define the pyramid function as, $z = f(x,y)$.
We are looking at 5 planes making up the pyramid. The 4 base points and apex are located at $ z(-X,-Y) = 0, \quad  z(X,-Y) = 0, \quad z(X,Y) = 0, \quad z(-X,Y) = 0, \quad z(0,0) = 1 $ respectively. Then the equation for the planes will be,
$$
\begin{align}
base \quad &: \quad z = 0 \\
front(-X \leq x \leq X, -Y \leq y \leq 0) \quad &: \quad z = 1 + \frac{y}{Y} \\
back(-X \leq x \leq X, 0 \leq y \leq Y) \quad &: \quad z = 1 - \frac{y}{Y} \\
left(-X \leq x \leq 0, -Y \leq y \leq Y) \quad &: \quad z = 1 + \frac{x}{X} \\
front(0 \leq x \leq X, -Y \leq y \leq Y) \quad &: \quad z = 1 - \frac{x}{X}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Please define what you mean by a Pyramid function

Comment: Define the pyramid function as f(x,y). Consider the 4 base points of the pyramid to be (-X,-Y,0), (X,-Y,0), (X,Y,0), (-X,Y,0). Consider the apex of the pyramid at (0,0,1).

Comment: @MHGadgil That is not a function, but rather $5$ points.

Comment: Please format your question with TeX markup. As it stands, it's unreadable.

Comment: sorry for the earlier format, I have now improved the format of the question

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x,y)$ be the function supported on $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$ and there given by $\min\left(1-|x|,1-|y|\right)$. We have:

$$\widehat{f}(u,v) = \frac{2 v \cos v \sin u-2 u\cos u\sin v}{\pi  u^3 v-\pi  u v^3}$$
and you just need to adjust the above transform by scaling and translating.

Comment: (1−|x|)(1−|y|) will be the convolution of 2 triangular functions. This will not be a pyramid, right? Hope my edited question justifies this comment.

Comment: @MHGadgil: you are right, I took that wrong at the first place. Now fixed.